# YAML internationalization

Tags: php, yaml

I'm working in a big project.I'm thinking of a new idea to create the best way of internacianalization to many languages.

**Solutions:**

- 1.Store data as arrays - tree file system.. It's not a good way because i need to modify files "on air".
- 2.I18n table.All translations have a common table or relative tables.(Queries to database + database cache)
- 3.YAML(it's new for me)

I am reading about YAMl documentation and I like this structure..I suggest the 3rd solution.
I would like to hear your opinions/suggestions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `gettext`? It is made for it... The objection to the 1st is somewhat alleviated by `var_export` btw...

Comment: @Wrikken I have never heard about it. Interesting solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK,I have no answers.
I will describe here my solutions for localization

For a common translations I used **Yaml** format.
(Data has this format):
Filename:**common.en_US.yaml**

```
menu:
  clients: Clients
  other: Other
  management: Management
```

**How to use it:**

```
l10n::get('menu/clients');
```

For the javaScript  translations,I used the same **yaml** format.

[image: java script yaml localization]
**How to use it:**
For the large dynamic data, I used **l10n** localization standart.
Where localization table has a prefix **_l10n**

```
l10n::get_data('table',68);
```