# How to go about allowing plugins for a custom framework?

Tags: php

First off, this isn't really a programming question but more of a programming concept question. Basically, I've built a bespoke PHP framework to speed up deployment on my end and I want some kind of plugin system in place that will allow me to add specific features to the base of the framework (like the SQL class or maybe a Twitter package) that will allow me to throw them into a folder and not have to actually edit the base for every new project.

Any ideas of the best way of going about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to allow plugins for a PHP application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42/best-way-to-allow-plugins-for-a-php-application)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nicely written post by [@ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell) on how to do that and what are the options:

- [Handling Plugins In PHP](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/03/handling-plugins-in-php.html)

Also check out:

- [Best way to allow plugins for a PHP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42/best-way-to-allow-plugins-for-a-php-application)

Comment: I've had a look into this and it seems to be going in the correct direction according to what I want but I'm a bit perplexed. Would I have to go through my code and add certain notifiers to events so a plugin could run a piece of code there? For instance:

   `//Original code
function save() {
 $this->anObjectsGotToDoWhatAnObjectsGotToDo();
 $this->plugins->notify();
}

//Plugin
function recieveNotification() {
 echo 'Model saved!';
}`

Answer (score 0):

what im doing in my cms:

- for each plugin i make a folder latin-named of this plugin's name.
- i create a **/translations** folder in there too. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971363/php-localization/10971942#10971942).
- have a single php file that has **2 basic functions**, the **plugin_install** and **plugin_uninstall** (you know, things to happen on install/unistall like tables creation/drop)
- create a *special page* of your system that reads these plugins, installed and not and give an **on/off switch** so users can install/unistall them.
- load these single files mentioned above by a single call to include_once on top of your index page (or administration page) so to `include whatever functionality they offer`.
- enabled plugins will be loaded (include_once) from your main page, and also their functionality, so each plugin can call each other's as well.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question :) I'm not talking about plugins for a web application, but specifically for a framework.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, understood. You wanted hooks. The links @Sarfraz are good enough.