# Convert datetime in GMT+# format to GMT

Tags: php, datetime, gmt

i have an input format like this, and i need to convert it to GMT format:

```
$input = array(
           "gmt" => "+7",
           "datetime" => "2017-10-10 12:10:12"
         );
```

the input data contain gmt array index which show the which gmt format, and the datetime index shows the date in "Y-m-d h:i:s" that needs to be convert from GMT+7 to GMT.

Comment: I Think you want to read about localization  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971363/php-localization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$input = array(
  "gmt" => "+7",
  "datetime" => "2017-10-10 12:10:12"
);

$ny = new DateTimeZone("GMT+7");
$gmt = new DateTimeZone("GMT");
$date = new DateTime( $input["datetime"], $ny );
$date->setTimezone( $gmt );

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneshot (not recommended):

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($input['datetime'])+$input['gmt']*3600);
```